# How to format/beautify HTML, CSS and JavaScript code in core JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, js-beautify

I am trying to format code using the following JS-based plugin:
https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify

All the examples are using NodeJS (it seems). I am only looking for a simple vanilla/code JavaScript solution.

Something like this:

```
let sourceContent = " function test() { ... }"
console.log(js-beautify(sourceContent));
```

Are there any available plugins out there? A jQuery solution is also fine.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133408/how-to-pretty-print-source-code-of-common-languages-in-browser-html-output-with

Comment: @Casburn Related indeed but not a duplicate, this question asks about a specific library not about a generic solution/suggested library as in the link above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The examples use nodejs but the library supports browsers too, as stated in the readme.

So add the (js beautify) script tag as mentioned in the readme:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-beautify/1.10.0/beautify-js.min.js"></script>
```

Then you can use the following example code:

```
const sourceContent = "function test() { ... }";
const beautified = js_beautify(sourceContent);
```

The web library is mentioned here:
https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify/blob/master/README.md#web-library

The available web methods are mentioned here: https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify/blob/master/README.md#web-library-1

So yes, you were very close with `js-beautify()` instead of `js_beautify()` :)